# Adsense Management Api Dimension URL_CHANNEL_(NAME/ID) not working

Tags: adsense-api

I am trying to update my adsense management api from 0.6.7 to 1.0.0 and am having difficulty when running a report for my url channels. I am passing the dimensions "date" and "url_channel_name" into the new api and it does not return any rows but I do get rows back with the old api. I need to use "url_channel_name" over "domain_name" so that all sub domains are grouped. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing "date" or "DATE"?

Comment: All dimensions and metrics passed are capitalized.

Comment: Have you had a look at the samples for v1.x? https://github.com/googleads/googleads-adsense-examples/tree/master/php-clientlib-1.x/v1.x